# Powershell parameters passing in for loop to function

Tags: powershell, parameters

i'm new to powershell, i have a specific task and would like to create a port scanner in powershell that allows to pass parameters in a foreach loop to a specific parameter in the function.

The function is called testport, the specific parameter i would like to pass when running the function in a for loop is $a - which would be a list of IP's i'm interested in scanning. Here's the function:

```
function testport ($hostname='10.0.0.$a',$port=445,$timeout=100) {
$requestCallback = $state = $null
$client = New-Object System.Net.Sockets.TcpClient
$beginConnect = $client.BeginConnect($hostname,$port,$requestCallback,$state)
Start-Sleep -milli $timeOut
if ($client.Connected) { $open = $true } else { $open = $false }
$client.Close()
[pscustomobject]@{hostname=$hostname;port=$port;open=$open}
```

the foreach loop to run the function would look like this:

```
foreach ($a in 1..255) {testport}
```

when ran, it runs against 10.0.0.$a multiple times, instead of 10.0.0.1, 10.0.0.2 etc.
How can i make this run properly?

Comment: What you're doing here is a bit of an antipattern, but you can make it work by changing `'10.0.0.$a'` to `$("10.0.0.$a")` in the parameter list

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cant use `$a` in your functions `$hostname` parameter default value as `$a` doesnt exist until powershell gets to the foreach statement (after its already read your function). At best `$a` will already exist and have some unknown value, or it wont exist at all - either way you get the wrong output. Your on the right lines, but you need to make some adjustments...

I would advise you make your testing function generic (so it accepts a normal IP), then in your for loop put your logic to generate the IPs to scan.

So your for loop might look something like:

```
foreach ($a in 1..255) {
  Write-Host "Testing ports on 10.0.0.$a";
  testport -hostname "10.0.0.$a"
}
```

Then i would alter the function signature to remove `$hostname`'s default value (`'10.0.0.$a'`). Your `testport` function declaration should look like this:

```
function testport ($hostname,$port=445,$timeout=100)
```

(NOTE: if you explicitly pass `$hostname` a value it will use that value instead of the default - but given the IP will always be different it probably doesnt make sense to give it a default value)

Comment: It worked! Thank you very much for the through explanation, looks something like this:

function testport ($hostname=$a,$port=445,$timeout=100) {
>>   $requestCallback = $state = $null
>>   $client = New-Object System.Net.Sockets.TcpClient
>>   $beginConnect = $client.BeginConnect($hostname,$port,$requestCallback,$state)
>>   Start-Sleep -milli $timeOut
>>   if ($client.Connected) { $open = $true } else { $open = $false }
>>   $client.Close()
>>   [pscustomobject]@{hostname=$hostname;port=$port;open=$open}
>> }

loop:
foreach ($a in 1..190) {testport -hostname "10.0.0.$a"}